# What register do I use to control the PWM clock on the BCM2835 used in the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pwm

What is the register used for setting a divisor on the PWM clock on the BCM2835? I looked at the data sheet (Raspberry-Pi-BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals) - but couldn't find this information.

But this information must be available somewhere, because going through the [wiringPi code](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi2-Python/blob/master/WiringPi/wiringPi/wiringPi.c), I find:

```
#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE   0x20000000
#define CLOCK_BASE  (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x00101000)
#define PWMCLK_DIV  41
...
clk = (uint32_t *)mmap(0, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, CLOCK_BASE) ;
...
*(clk + PWMCLK_DIV) = BCM_PASSWORD | (divisor << 12) ;
```

I don't know where 0x00101000 and 41 are coming from. Could you point me to documentation that explains the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember where the location of the PWM and PCM clocks is documented.  The [peripherals document](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) does give the locations of GPCLK0/1/2.

All the clocks are accessed from the clock peripheral.  The normally used ones are at these offsets from the base register (0x20101000).

```
#define CLK_GP0_CTL 28
#define CLK_GP0_DIV 29
#define CLK_GP1_CTL 30
#define CLK_GP1_DIV 31
#define CLK_GP2_CTL 32
#define CLK_GP2_DIV 33

#define CLK_PCM_CTL 38
#define CLK_PCM_DIV 39

#define CLK_PWM_CTL 40
#define CLK_PWM_DIV 41
```

The operation of the clocks is described from page 105 of the peripherals document.  That explains the registers.

More example code at [Minimal clock access](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_code).

EDITED TO ADD

More info about PWM/PCM clocks at [clocks addendum](https://www.scribd.com/doc/127599939/BCM2835-Audio-clocks)

Another useful source is the [eLinux errata](http://elinux.org/BCM2835_datasheet_errata)

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get the base register value 0x20101000 from? I couldn't find that in the data sheet.

Comment: Honestly I don't remember.  Probably just someones post.  The kernel sources for the Pi would be one way of finding these values.  I added more info to my post.

Comment: I had seen the errata and page 105. The latter talks only about GP0, GP1, GP2 - no mention of PCM and PWM clocks. I wish this information was easier to find.

Comment: The clocks addendum has the information. The 0x7e1010a0 CM_PWMCT register address is 0x7e000000 + 0x101000 + 41*sizeof(int)

Comment: Found the complete [BCM2835 register information](http://elinux.org/BCM2835_registers) (thanks to my pal Ravi).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [wiringpi](http://wiringpi.com/) C library, which provides software pwm channels, I use it to drive some LEDs.

Comment: I am trying to understand the hardware PWM pins. I already got it to work. What I am looking for is the register information, which I can't seem to find in the specs.

Comment: @marko-frelih You'd probably be better off using hardware timed PWM from the likes of [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/). Less likely to get visible glitches.